# Multiple standard headers with same name - which one gets included and how can I change it?

Tags: c++11, gcc, arm

I'm getting an error that `std::enable_if_t` does not name a template type. Funny enough it is included by a line `#include <type_traits>` at the top of the file. But looking into some of the other standard headers, there is another file named type_traits in a different directory that doesn't define `enable_if_t`. How does gcc decide which of these files to use and how can I change it?

The path of the file I want to use is:

```
.../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1/type_traits
```

I don't know what file gcc is using but these files do not have the definition that should solve my problem:

```
.../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/cpp_type_traits.h
.../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1/ext/type_traits.h
.../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1/experimental/type_traits
.../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1/tr2/type_traits
.../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1/tr1/type_traits
```

Comment: gcc has a list of standard places to search. You can print the list with the `-v` (IIRC) compiler flag. It is highly unlikely that  .../tr1 or .../tr2 are on that list by default. Perhaps you have added these directories with `-I`?

Comment: You also can print names of files which are in fact ncluded (with full paths) by supplying the `-H` compiler flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your tags, you are compiling with `-std=c++11`. The C++11 standard library
does not define `std::enable_if_t`. C++14 defines it and the standard library
headers will expose it only if you compile with `-std=c++14`.

In C++11, write `std::enable_if<B,T>::type` instead of `std::enable_if_t<B,T>`. C++14
defines:

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;
```

C++11 does not.

See [documentation of `std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

You cannot infer, simply by finding a declaration or definition of *X* in
some standard header that this declaration or definition will be visible
to your compiler with given compilation options, because the header file will
be preprocessed, normally causing different parts to be compiled depending on
compilation options, including the `-std` option, and perhaps configuration
options of your implementation.

Comment: This makes more sense I guess. What's confusing me is that I'm moving a project from IAR over to gcc. Both are trying to use c++11 but somehow IAR seems to be throwing in some additional c++14 features (like enable_if_t). It's pretty confusing and annoying. Thanks for the help